# How to reproduce flatMap using foreach and concat in Scala?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to recreate the `flatMap` function using `foreach` and `List.concat` but the resulting list seems unchanged.

Here's the reference:

```
val rdd: List[String] = List("Hello sentence one",
                             "This is the next sentence",
                             "The last sentence")
val fm: List[String] = rdd.flatMap(s => s.split("\\W"))
println(fm)
```

which gives:

```
List(Hello, sentence, one, This, is, the, next, sentence, The, last, sentence)
```

And here is my approach to recreate the same:

```
val nonRdd: List[String] = List("Hello sentence one",
                                "This is the next sentence",
                                "The last sentence")
var nonfm: List[String] = List()
nonRdd.foreach(line => List.concat(nonfm, line.split("\\W")))
println("nonfm: " + nonfm)
```

So every line is split on word and the resulting, intermediate line is supposed to be concatenated to the previously initialized list `nonfm`.

However, `nonfm` is empty:

```
nonfm: List()
```

Comment: That list is immutable. List.concat returns a new list, you need to assign it to the variable

Comment: I thought declaring it as `var` makes it mutable, as opposed to declaring it with `val`.

Comment: doesn't matter. The List implementation you are using is immutable by nature. There is no interface to mutate it whether you are using a variable or not. The variable allows you to mutate the memory address of the reference to the List value, not the contents of the List itself. If you want a mutable list, you need to use this => https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/collection/mutable/MutableList.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I have mentioned in the comments section, `List` in Scala will default to `scala.collection.immutable`

As the [documentation suggests](http://scala.collection.immutable), concat returns a new list rather than mutating the original one (it couldn't anyway since it's immutable)

> Returns a new sequence containing the elements from the left hand operand followed by the elements from the right hand operand.

So you need to update the variable on every iteration with a simple assignment

```
val nonRdd: List[String] = List("Hello sentence one",
                                "This is the next sentence",
                                "The last sentence")
var nonfm: List[String] = List()
nonRdd.foreach(line => nonfm = List.concat(nonfm, line.split("\\W")))
println("nonfm: " + nonfm)
```

Based on the use of the word RDD, I am guessing you are going to be using Spark eventually. I am hoping you are simply experimenting and trying to understand how things work, but please ***do not ever use*** **variables** in Spark (or in Scala in general). See @Avishek's answer for why they will break your program in Spark

Comment: Appreciate your worries:) you are correct it's mostly for me to be sure I understand what flat map is doing and surely I also appreciate the elegance of remaining within the RDD context (that's why its amply called `nonRdd`).

Comment: @TMOTTM Understood, if that is your goal, please note that as much as it is discouraged, for performance reasons `flatMap` on `Lists` is implemented as a while loop in Scala. `foreach` is really associated with side-effects so it gets confusing to use it to process data. It is also important to note flatMap is not a property of collections but of Monads (in this case List Monad), that's why you can flatMap over Option etc. and the implementation differs for each Monad.

Answer (score 1):

This is right behaviour. The variable `var nonfm: List[String] = List()` is defined in the master. When you run the `nonRdd.foreach(line => List.concat(nonfm, line.split("\\W")))` each partition of the nonRdd gets its own copy of the `nonfm`.

When the foreach runs, master sends each rdd partition the closure i.e. code and variables by serializing it. These partitions might be running in completely different machine altogether.

Finally, when you do `println("nonfm: " + nonfm)` it prints the `nonfm` declared in the master. This copy of the variable hasn't been mutated at all. Thus provides empty result.